# 2 Dimensional jQuery Slider - CSS Positioning

Tags: jquery, css, slider, html

So, I'm trying to build a two dimensional content slider and I'm having problems implementing it. I'm using jQuery.

The basic idea for the slider markup is:

```
<div id="contentSlider">
    <div class="contentBlock">
        <div class="pictures">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="img1.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img2.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img3.jpg" />
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="absPositionedNavUp></div>
            <div class="absPositionedNavDown></div>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <p>
                Blah blah yadda yadda.
                Blah blah yadda yadda.
                Blah blah yadda yadda.
                Blah blah yadda yadda.
            </p>
            <p>
                Blah blah yadda yadda.
                Blah blah yadda yadda.
                Blah blah yadda yadda.
                Blah blah yadda yadda.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contentBlock">
        ........
    </div>
    <div class="contentBlock">
        ........
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slideAllContentLeft"></div>
<div class="slideAllContentRight"></div>
```

What I'm trying to do (and I've been able to get certain parts working) is:

(1) Have the pictures div slide up and down between images

(2) Have the contentSlider div slide left and right between multiple contentBlock divs

What I have currently is at: http://www.ficreates.com/_SiteDemos/PBL/projects.html

My main issue is with the CSS part of it. How do I get the divs to line up left to right and slide between them?  You can see my code currently, which is prob about 60% of the way there.

Comment: The other thing that I'm having a problem with (not a huge deal) is: the photos are exactly 330px high, but there's an unexplained margin/border between them. I set the slide amount to 332px which sort of works, but the margin must be a partial pixel amount (like 1.5px or something like that) because eventually the next photo's edge starts to creep in.

Comment: I would advise to put the last image before the first during the initialization, so the user won't see a black square if he goes up the first time. And if the user goes up the last (I presume that's the bottom one) before the first, and down first after the last.

Comment: For the margin-thing try a general reset like `margin: 0;`, `border-width: 0;` `padding: 0;`.

Comment: Yeah. I'll have to loop the left to right slide as well, but that shouldn't be hard... I just haven't done it yet.

Comment: Reset doesn't work.  :(

I already have a general reset.css file that I link to for cross-browser defaults. I didn't have the border-width thing, but I just added it and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: hmmm... Now I'm curious.

Comment: The dimension of the phantom-margin is exactly: 1.5px... WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, and the solution is something like the following:

Create a container div for the content blocks.  It's width is set by: the jQuery length property (which calculates the total number of content blocks) times the width of a single content block (950px). The container div is then positioned left to right using absolute positioning within the .content_slider div.

The phantom border was actually a problem with the line-height which was set in my reset.css file (the ul was inheriting "line-height:1;"). I overrode this with "line-height: 0;" and voila, no more 1.5px space between the individual photos.

- For a look at the final product: http://www.ficreates.com/_SiteDemos/PBL/projects.html
- For the javascript, visit: http://www.ficreates.com/_SiteDemos/PBL/scripts/projWidg.js